# SQL Server - Syntax around UNION and USE functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

have a series of databases on the same server which i am wishing to query. I am using the same code to query the database and would like the results to appear in a single list.

I am using 'USE' to specify which database to query, followed by creating some temporary tables to group my data, before using a final SELECT statement to bring together all the data from the database.

I am then using UNION, followed by a second USE command for the next database and so on.

SQL Server is showing a syntax error on the word 'UNION' but does not give any assistance as to the source of the problem.

Is it possible that I am missing a character. At present I am not using ( or ) anywhere.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Don't use `set`, fully qualify your tables instead: `database.schema.table`

Answer (score 3):

The `USE` statement just redirects your session to connect to a different database on the same instance, you don't actually need to switch from database to database in this matter (there are a few rare exceptions tho).

Use the 3 part notation to join your result sets. You can do this while being connected to any database.

```
SELECT
    SomeColumn = T.SomeColumn
FROM
    FirstDatabase.Schema.TableName AS T
UNION ALL
SELECT
    SomeColumn = T.SomeColumn
FROM
    SecondDatabase.Schema.YetAnotherTable AS T
```

The engine will automatically check for your login's users on each database and validate your permissions on the underlying tables or views.

`UNION` adds result sets together, you can't issue another operation (like `USE`) other than `SELECT` between `UNION`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the database names before the table name:

```
SELECT valueFromBase1
 FROM `database1`.`table1`
  WHERE ...
UNION
SELECT valueFromBase2
 FROM `database2`.`table2`
  WHERE ...
```